# Postgres: see statement generated implictly by FKs?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.6 in Ubuntu.

With many tables and many foreign keys, when I delete certain data it generates the respective commands implicitly to clean up the foreign relations.

This can be "seen" when a long running `DELETE` statement is interrupted with e.g. `CTRL-c` it shows which "background" statement was running.

Is there  way to see all the statements which are generated/executed in the  background? The `log_statement` configuration does not show them either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way, but it's possible with an `ExecutorStart_hook`.

The [`auto_explain` contrib module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) can trace "nested" statements. See `auto_explain.log_nested_statements`. I'm not sure if it ignores FK checks or considers them; the nested statements feature is mainly used for things like PL/PgSQL.